# curl php post - Service Unavailable - Maximum number of active clients reached

Tags: php, post, curl, connection, http-status-code-503

Hello I am doing `curl` PHP POST request (because of the cross domain origin) and I am facing a problem. Post request is send to a machine that hosts some custom web server that I can't control. First requests (like 15-20 are ok) but after this number of requests I am getting `503 error` response with the error message

> Service Unavailable - Maximum number of active clients reached.

I suppose that curl is creating a new connection every time I send a request. I also suppose that the machine server can have only a few connections opened.

Here is my php code:

```
$data = array("getTags" => array("Start_dav","CutON"), "includeTagMetadata" => false);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://domainipaddres/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "SID=8c81775da6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
       'Connection: Keep-alive',
       'Keep-alive: 300'
    )                                                                       
);  

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);   
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I really need to figure it out but after 2 days of trying different options and header datas I cant get it working. How to force curl to use only one connection?

Thank you very much

EDIT: I found a problem today. Server can only have 3 active clients. I found that in first response header from server is SET cookie and I need to use that cookie in another requests. I set it manually and it works. Is there any way how to do this automatically?

Comment: Sounds like the other server is very limited, and can only handle a few operations a second. In other words, it's not the connection that's the problem but a lack of processing power on their end.

Comment: after I get 503 response the next request works after I wait cca 10 minutes. But first like 20 requests that are not send in the row are ok. thats what is weird abbout it. I think that if the connection is immediately closed after request it should be ok. Or maybe if curl uses the same connection for request if its still alive. That shouldnt be doing problems

Comment: I'd try without curl options CURLOPT_COOKIE, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE. See what happens without it...

Comment: Also, don't execute curl_close($ch); as long as you're going to issue another POST...

Comment: nothing helps. still the same problem. I read somewhere that Curl doesnt response to last FIN flag. Maybe that is the problem. There is no way to watch if curl is openning a new connection or no

Comment: I found a problem today see my edit please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem today. I inspected response header and saw that server sets cookies. I just had to save cookies and use it in another requests and its working. Here is part of the code:

```
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U;Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.8.0.9) Gecko/20061206 Firefox/1.5.0.9';
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
$f = fopen('request.txt', 'w'); //writes headers to this file
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"domainipaddress");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);
$tmpfname = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'; //saves the cookie from server
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,  CURLOPT_VERBOSE,  1 ); 
curl_setopt( $ch,  CURLOPT_STDERR,  $f );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);                                                                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                        
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
       'Connection: keep-alive',
       "Keep-Alive: 300"
    )                                                                       
);  

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
fclose($f);
```

Thank you anyway